# How to convert time with timezone in ruby

Tags: ruby, time, timezone

I want to convert time by passing time with timezone for conversion.

Writing a single method which convert time with timezone.

```
Time.now + Time.zone_offset("PST")
```

Will it work ?

i need a method in ruby.

Comment: Which version of Ruby are you using? And there's no method like: `Time.zone_offset("PST")` in Ruby(unless you're using Rails).

Comment: @User089247 Am using ruby - 2.0.0p247v. I dont know how to convert. which method i have to use.

Comment: Apologies, I was incorrect. You can do: `Time.now + Time.zone_offset("PST")` if you: `require 'time'` in your ruby script. guess, should have done that before commenting. So, what exactly are you looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no method for that, however you can make one for yourself:

```
class Time
  require 'time'
  def self.by_offset(offset)
    at(now + zone_offset(offset))
  end
end
```

Now, you can:

```
Time.by_offset('PST')
#=> 2014-11-03 10:11:14 +0530
Time.now
#=> 2014-11-03 18:11:13 +0530
```

Tested with 1.9.2, 2.0.0, and 2.1.2 Rubies(MRI).

Comment: Found it.. Its strange.. My output is something other than you.. :-(

Comment: Opps! that's true.. Got it.. I forgot we are in different time zone.. hehehehe :-)

Answer (score 4):

"PST" only represents the part of the Pacific time zone that falls into Pacific Standard Time.  To fully represent the time zone, you must consider Pacific Daylight Time also.

To do this in Ruby, you should use the [tzinfo gem](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/tzinfo/frames), as follows:

```
require 'tzinfo'
tz = TZInfo::Timezone.get('America/Los_Angeles')
now = tz.now
```

See also "Time Zone != Offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Answer (score 0):

No direct method is present. But you can solve it as

```
>> a = %w(%Y %m %d %H %M %S)
=> ["%Y", "%m", "%d", "%H", "%M", "%S"]
>> tm = Time.now
=> 2014-11-03 17:46:02 +0530
>> a.map { |s| tm.strftime(s) }
=> ["2014", "11", "03", "17", "46", "02"]
>> a.map! { |s| tm.strftime(s).to_i }
=> [2014, 11, 3, 17, 46, 2]
>> Time.new(*a, Time.zone_offset('PST'))
=> 2014-11-03 17:46:02 -0800
```

Look at the [`new(year, month=nil, day=nil, hour=nil, min=nil, sec=nil, utc_offset=nil) → time`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Time.html#method-c-new) documentation. [`utc_offset` for PST](http://www.prokerala.com/travel/timezones/Pacific_Standard_Time) is `-08:00`.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at **[`in_time_zone`](http://apidock.com/rails/DateTime/in_time_zone)**

```
 > Time.zone = 'Hawaii'  
 => "Hawaii" 
 > DateTime.now.in_time_zone 
 => Mon, 03 Nov 2014 04:00:29 HST -10:00   # UTC-10:00
 > DateTime.now
 => Mon, 03 Nov 2014 19:30:41 +0530  # UTC+05:30
 > Time.zone = "Eastern Time (US & Canada)"
 => "Eastern Time (US & Canada)" 
 > DateTime.now.in_time_zone
 => Mon, 03 Nov 2014 09:03:34 EST -05:00
```

Comment: `in_time_zone` is a Rails method, and thus not available for general Ruby usage.