# How to alter the timezone of a Time in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, time, timezone

Suppose I have a Time object with a timezone (say, UTC). I want to reset the timezone to an *arbitrary* one (aka, not your local timezone) **without altering** any other parameters of the Time like "hour".
Ruby as of Version 3.3 doesn't seem to provide any single method to do it (cf., [Official doc](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.3/Time.html) of Time and [Stackoverflow answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26713903/how-to-convert-time-with-timezone-in-ruby)). How can I achieve this, then?

I note that for the DateTime class, the `change` method (seemingly) works as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4467781/how-do-i-alter-the-timezone-of-a-datetime-in-ruby) [**Edit**: it is a [Rails method](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.1/classes/DateTime.html#method-i-change)]. However,

> DateTime class is considered deprecated. Use Time class.

as [in Ruby 3](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.3/DateTime.html) and so I want to know how to do it with Time class.

I also note that Rails implements some convenient methods as mentioned in [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16818180/ruby-rails-change-the-timezone-of-a-time-without-changing-the-value); but they are not available in pure Ruby (and in fact, [`in_time_zone`](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html#method-i-in_time_zone) of Rails changes another time parameter, `hour`).

How can I do it in pure Ruby?

Comment: FYI: `change` is also a Rails method, the built-in [`Datetime`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.3/DateTime.html) class doesn’t have one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Time instance is immutable, meaning it is impossible to *alter* an existing Time object. Alternativly, it is possible, though slightly awkward to do in pure Ruby (cf., [Official doc](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.3/Time.html)), to create a new Time instance based on an existing one, in which you set a new arbitrary "timezone […] without altering any other parameters of the Time", namely copying them all from the existing Time to the new one.

I here list a few ways (*Note*: no singleton methods or instance variables are inherited):

```rb
require "time"
t = Time.now(in: "+00:00")
  # => <2024-02-24 01:23:45 +0000>

t1= Time.new(*(t.to_a.reverse[4..-1]), in: "+09:00")
  # => <2024-02-24 01:23:45 +0900>

t2= Time.new(t.year, t.month, t.day, t.hour, t.min, t.sec+t.subsec, in: "+09:00")
  # => <2024-02-24 01:23:45 ... +0900>

ar = t.strftime("%Y %m %d %H %M %S %N").split.map(&:to_i)
t3= Time.new(*(ar[0..4]+[ar[5]+ar[6].quo(1_000_000_000), "+09:00"]))
  # => <2024-02-24 01:23:45 ... +0900>

t4= Time.at(t, in: "+09:00") - 9*3600
  # => <2024-02-24 01:23:45.... +0900>
```

Here, `t1` only considers down to a second, whereas the others consider down to a nanosecond.

`t2` is the most intuitive, but it is the most cumbersome. Here,[`Time#subsec`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.2/Time.html#method-i-subsec) returns a Rational and hence the formula involves no floating-point rounding error.

`t3` may have no benefit over `t2`.  It involves no floating-point rounding error as in `t2`.

Although `t4` is less lengthy, the facts that it is against the DRY principle and that you *must* accurately specify the parity (plus or minus?) are significant downsides.

Comment: `t.tv_nsec.to_f/1e9` is prone to floating point rounding errors. Use `t.subsec` instead, which returns a precise value.

Comment: @Stefan Good point! I edited the answer so it uses `t.subsec` instead of `tv_nsec.to_f`. Thanks!

Comment: Regarding _"no easy ways to achieve this"_ – time instances are immutable in Ruby. If you want to change _any_ of the attributes (not just timezone, this also applies to year, month, day, hour, minute, etc.) you have to create a new instance and pass the modified attributes accordingly.